# What is the need of re-sampling the image in HOG features?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I read [Dalal and Triggs](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) paper for HOG description and a blog by [Chris McCormick](http://mccormickml.com/2013/05/09/hog-person-detector-tutorial/) regarding the same. The blog says that the image needs to be re-sampled at different scales to recognize different person.

My question is: Already we have a window which we place on the image having a size of 64*128 and which slides over the image. Then why re-sampling instead of sliding the whole window over the image which can detect the persons instead. ?

Please rectify if I am wrong, thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the fact that the size of 64*128 is trained to be classified as either 'person' or 'non person'. But do all the persons in  real world images always come in a handy 64*128 size?

That is where the scaling comes to play. By progressively making image smaller, the same 64*128 pixel region will cover larger area in the original image allowing detection of multiple sizes people.

For example,Here is an example from one of my models after running the detection on multiple scales. The result presented is after applying non-maximal supression to weed out extreneous detection windows.

[image]